# How to recover photos from facotry reset S6?

Tags: data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-6

So, somehow my S6 factory reset while it was in my pocket while I was climbing. Still not sure how. But I need to recover the photo files off of it, whatever might still be left in the slack space. I figured I'd just mount it up and run foremost over it, but apparently there's no way to mount it as a USB Mass Storage Device? sigh What are my alternatives? Is there any way to get it to show up in linux as a /dev/sdx device so that I can run some forensic tools over it?

Comment: A factory-reset usually leaves the SD cards untouched. Where were your photos stored? And true, no UMS anymore (that was replaced by MTP starting with ICS/4.0). For a starter, please take a look at our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) and [these related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[data-recovery]+factory+reset+photos+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 0):

Sad to say but if it factory reset your stuff is gone. only way if possible would be to use some recovery tools in kali linux but then again a phone is not same as a PC hdd. i'd just count your loses and start backing up. stupid samsung :(